# MVVM View Model Collections with Web API, View Model and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mvvm, asp.net-web-api

question about collection helper classes for view models with in a Web API <> View Models <> Entity Framework <> Database structure.

I'm trying to get a design started on a project which will use an "API" front end to get data, then HTML/Javascript pages to get and render.

In trying to create an MVVM approach to this I am not sure if what I want to implment is a good approch or not.

And that is a get Collection methods for the ViewModels. The user on the HTML side, will only be able to edit one Object at a time, so the collection is only to provide arrays/listing of the objects, making the Web API classes "less cluttered".

Using the Visual Studio MVC/Web API porject / c# (Visual Studio 2013 so MVC 5 components)

so using example of a Chair object

NOTE: in actual code would not do "new MyEntity().Chairs." all the time, it would be set as a variable with in the class. Simply written example long hand to make clear.

**Web API part**:
we will pluralize api objects front point
Web API controller = ChairsController
With 2 gets

```
namespace FurnitureAPI.Controllers
{
[Authorize]
public class ChairsController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/chairs
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var chairs = ViewModels.Chairs.Get();
        return Ok(chairs);
    }

    // GET api/chairs/5
    //public string Get(int id)
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var chair = ViewModels.Chairs.Get(id);
        return Ok(chair);
    }
```

public ... GET() {...} //all chairs
  public ... GET(int id) {} //single chair where id

In the **database** side, we have Chair table. This will be singular for database.
Database already exists, so using **Entity Framework** and database first modelling we get in Entities

```
 var furniture_db = new Models.FurnintureEntities();
```

and

```
Models.Chair
```

So in the middle want a **View Model** Chair.

```
namespace FurnitureAPI.ViewModels {
public class Chair {
    public int ChairID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Chair() { }
    public Chair(int chairid, string name) {
        ChairID = chairid;
        Name = name;
    }
    public Chair(Models.Chair db_chair) {
        ChairID = db_chair.ChairID;
        Name = db_chair.Name;
    }
}
```

In my thinking, the Web API ChairsController I do not want to have any entity framework code.
but I want api to call something to get a List/Collection of Chair view models

So Im thinking, add **Chairs** as a class in the ViewModel namespace, which will be static.

so web api becomes

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var chairs = ViewModels.Chairs.Get();
    return Ok(chairs);
}
```

and the View Model Collection Chairs then looks like

```
namespace FurnitureAPI.ViewModels {
public static class Chairs {
    public static List<Chair> Get() {
        List<Chair> chairs = (from s in new Models.FurnintureEntities().Chairs
                                                    select new ViewModel.Chair {
                                                        ChairID = s.ChairID,
                                                        Name = s.Name
                                                    }).ToList();

        return chairs;
    }

    public static Chairs Get(int id) {
        var chair = new FurnitureEntities().Chairs.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ChairID == id);
        return chair != null ? new ViewModel.Chair(chair) : null;
    }
}
```

So the question, is this Chairs collection wrapper okay/ideal/bad/run for the hills/other, or is there a different approach someone could point to?

I do not understand why struggling to find reference to on the internet, sure hope its not grumpy old age kicking in.
I find lots of WPF MVVM Entity Framework database first stuff, but I just want to make 'simple' Web API to expose the database to make HTML views with.

Maybe I do not need to bother with the View Model and simply serialize the Entity in the Web API methods?

Thanks.

Comment: Wow... you are hitting a lot of subjects here. Basically I would say that your viewmodels are to tightly coupled to your database layer. Do you have experience with IOC? (try googling `Unity` or `AutoFac`). For your mappings (the `select new` part you could use something like `AutoMapper`. This will centralize your mappings so you can reuse that code. These techniques will probably alter your pattern.

Comment: As a side note: in the MVVM pattern I tend to pass `DomainModels` through the API only, and let the API client create a viewmodel from that data. By passing `ViewModels` through the API, it suggests that that call is designed for a certain `view`, which (in my opinion) is a client-side thing. I know it is just a naming convention thing, but I prefer to look at it like this: if a 3rd party uses your API, would they like to receive viewsmodels or domain(data)models? I think its the latter and they will construct their own views.

Comment: @Stefan  in most cases, yes, viewmodels would be tightly coupled to the database layer. So viewing it again, could Entity Framework not be seen as a View Model? (in the concept term not name)?  and Model is actual database not Entity Framework as i have layed out above?

With that then, would it be acceptable in some cases in the Web API to call Entity Framework models directly, instead of via ViewModels. and make VM in the cases that Entity Framework is insufficient?

Would have issue with OK(ef_model_object) as ok cannot serialise EF, but that a different issue not related to this

Comment: In a way it might be, but only in concept. Basically you are omitting the separate layers and with that the separation of concern in your patterns. Using EF directly in your view always leads to more work when the slightest change is made to eighter the view or to the database. I have came across this issue a lot and it even contains security risks when there are a lot of relational ID's involved. At first it will seem a lot of work to create all those different viewmodels, but when the first change comes it will be worth the effort.

Comment: The main thing is: an API is not intended to expose a database. It's an application programming interface. This means its an abstraction of some application or logic. This logic usually lives in the application domain, not in the data layer. By using a separate view or domain model you can keep the API stable when you alter your database or even business rules :)

Comment: so breaking apart the chair object, I want to introduce having   1) api/Chairs to which also has 2) api/Chairs/4 and introduce 3)  api/ChairDetails/4. The first 1) returns list of 2), but Chair on its own is a simple description, 2-3 properties. where 3) has many more properties (if not all with reference details aswell - multiple db tables). In the database this would just be 1 table, but for API usage only interested is give full list with 2 properties, or full properties for specified object. 1 db model, 2 view models.

Comment: I am not sure if 2 types of chairs (plain and detailed) is really going to help you there. It seems hard to maintain. Although I like it because it is a perfect example of domain- vs data(EF)-models. :) One last tip: try to minimize the ID-fields in your view(domain)models. It can be hard to fetch all the relevant data that way. Or... try to use `natural-keys`.. perhaps your chairs have IKEA-like unique names; that would make the querying easier for 3th parties (if applicable), and keep your models cleaner. For the rest, I am afraid learning through experience (the hard way)...  :|

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I've been struggling with this too and it seems this subject doesn't get the love it should have.

Anyway, among the tools there are, you can count:

- [Breeze#](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.sharp) (MIT)
- [TrackableEntitities](https://github.com/trackableEntities/trackable-entities/) (MIT)